# Error: certificate has expired || first time running a project

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I started as a Junior Web Dev to contribute to an open-source.
After trying to set up the Dev Env I get these errors of "Error: certificate has expired".

I've found a solution, but I have no clue how to "export" env variables as suggested:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Simply write them before the actual command:

Linux/Mac OS

```bash
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' meteor
```

Or first export it, then run meteor as usual as shown below.

```bash
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
meteor
```

On Windows / Command Prompt

```bash
SET NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' && meteor
```

Comment: "'NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
 - Thats what I get when I do that

Comment: and if I try adding "set" to it, it just exits

Comment: Oh sorry that command I wrote is on bash you need the windows she'll equivalent, let me check this out.